# Percentage ( Debts & Assets )

Tags: percentages

A debtor can pay **87 paise in the rupee**, but if his creditors  would take 20%  of his debts, **he could pay them** and have  Rs. 42 left. Calculate his debts and assets.

I don't understand the bold part of the sentence. Please help me to understand this question.

Comment: how many paise in 1 rupee?

Comment: @danimal - Rs. 1= 100 paise.

Comment: so 87 piase in the rupee means 87%

Comment: @danimal - okay. But what does it mean if you read the whole sentence including the bold part? Does it mean that debtor have to pay 87%? But if creditors get 20%, thus debtor has to pay 67%?

Comment: Also "his creditors would take 20% of his debts" - just checking, does that mean he would have to pay 80% of his debt or 20% of his debt?

Comment: @Joffan : But what does 87 paise in the rupee mean then?

Comment: presumably, his assets are 87% of his debts, and the 20% is the proportion of his debts the creditors would take off his hands...

Comment: It means he has enough assets to pay 87% of his debt. He can't pay in full, so for each rupee they are owed the creditors would only receive 87 paise. The word "but" separates that scenario from the "20% of debts" scenario, so I don't read that 87% concept as active thereafter in the question.

Comment: @danimal & Joffan : Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given assets $a$ and debts $d$ (in rupees), the "87 paise in the rupee" $\implies a= 0.87d$

The "creditors would take 20% of his debt" alternative I interpret as $a= 0.8d+42$

Subtracting these gives $0.07d = 42$